# Find number of decompositions of direct sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, direct-sum

Find number of decomposition Z $\oplus$ A to direct sum B $\oplus$ C, where :

1) one of B, C is isomorphic to Z : B $\cong$ Z or C $\cong$ Z

2) Z is infinite and cycle, A is finite and abelian

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far?  Did you try working through an example?

Comment: Note: if $Z$ is infinite and cyclic, then $Z \cong \Bbb Z$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Honestly, i have no idea how to do this. May be i should find number of structures, which are isomorphic to Z(lets it is m) and which are isomorphic to A(n), and then our answer is nm. But I have problems with non-empty intersection and I should prove that this conditions are enough for isomorphism between direct sums.